# hyperlink to submit form on a different page

Tags: html, forms, post, hyperlink

Is there a way how link can **post** data to a form on **different** page?

I imagine something like this, but this only open the requested page in new window (which is fine), but leaves the form on that page unfilled and also unsubmitted.

```
<?php echo '
<form action="http://www.someweb.cz/info2/dochazka/dochazka.php" method="post">
    <input name="obdobi" type="hidden" value="'.$obdobi[Obdobi].'" />
    <input name="kurs" type="hidden" value="'.$kurz_vybrany.'" />
    <a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" 
        href="http://www.someweb.cz/info2/dochazka/dochazka.php?doc=start.htm" 
        onclick="this.form.submit();">'.$pocet_lidi.'</a>
</form>'; ?>
```

I can slightly modify the "action" page code, but I'd like to keep the POST method.

Comment: --nevermind, I see the anchor now; d'oh--

Comment: Do you mean to have a form auto-fill itself upon submitting data to it, on a different page?

Comment: Yes, that would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to accomplish via cURL. See Example #2 on the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('obdobi' => $obdobi[Obdobi],
    'kurs' => $kurz_vybrany);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.someweb.cz/info2/dochazka/dochazka.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your javascript a bit, since the use of `this` is actually referring to the anchor itself and not the window, the form, etc. (thus calling `this.form` isn't actually capturing the form, it's giving an undefined error).

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" onClick="this.parentNode.submit();">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Note the `parentNode` reference after this. Note [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sVADB/).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Nevertheless it behaves the same as it did before. New window with the form is displayed, but the form is not filled nor submitted. And java is now complaining that this.parentNode.submit(); is not a function.

Comment: @meridius: What browser are you using? And have you posted the exact code you're using? I have no problem in IE9, FF4&6 & Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I could not get either of suggested working. And because this was only a part of bigger project with deadline closing I decided to solve this by removing form, updating anchor to

```
<a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" 
    href="http://www.someweb.cz/info2/dochazka/dochazka.php
    ?doc=start.htm&obdobi='.$obdobi[Obdobi].'&kurs='.$kurz_vybrany.'">'.$pocet_lidi.'</a>
```

and adding

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET[kurs])) $kurs = $_GET[kurs];
    if (isset($_GET[obdobi])) $obdobi = $_GET[obdobi];
?>
```

to dochazka.php